# C# MSChart how to shift Y axis like oscilloscope offset button?

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a `MSChart`, that x-axis is t(ms), and y-axis is voltage data.
Now I would like programming the code like oscilloscope function "Offset".
When I adjust `numericUpDown` to shift the wave and Y-axis.
How to get this function? Just like below 2 picture.  Thanks!

[No shift wave and Y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgKdV.png)

[Now shift Y-axis and wave shift too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg4T7.png)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would tackle it is to change the y-axis `Minimum` and/or `Maximum` values. You can also play with the `IntervalOffset`.

See here:

[image]

```
private void numericUpDown5_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    int oy = (int)numericUpDown5.Value;

    if (radioButton1.Checked)  ay.IntervalOffset = oy;
    if (radioButton2.Checked)  ay.Maximum = oy;
    if (radioButton3.Checked)  ay.Minimum = oy;
}

private void rbAy_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    if (sender == radioButton1) numericUpDown5.Value = (decimal)ay.IntervalOffset;
    if (sender == radioButton2) numericUpDown5.Value = (decimal)ay.Maximum;
    if (sender == radioButton3) numericUpDown5.Value = (decimal)ay.Minimum;
}
```